# <img> in <canvas> not shown

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I'm trying to show an `<img>` element inside a `<canvas>` with Elm (via Javascript). "Inspect element" shows the added element, but it is not visible.

[image: screenshot]

It may be related to the `z-index` CSS property.

Comment: Could you provide real code or a link?

Comment: try giving the exact path for the image

Comment: you can't show an image element inside a canvas element. you should probably try [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) method of canvas. another workaround: place img tag outside canvas tag and set display inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show any items within a [canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_canvas.asp) element unless canvas is not supported in a browser then the contents will act as a fallback, if for instance you viewed your page in IE6 then you would see the image but the canvas would be unusuable.

Use [drawImage()](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) for canvas.